# Help to Understand the Proof of Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Below are sceen shots taken from Pugh's Book Real Mathematical Analysis.

My question mainly is from the proof below. How does it follow that $M<M$ from $b=c$? Thanks for your help.[image]

[image]

Comment: can you be specific what part u dont understand?

Comment: In Case 2 last part of the proof. How does it follow from $b=c$ that $M<M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Notice that during the first part of Case 2, we prove that the least upper bound of $V_c < M$, which means that the least upper bound of $f$ on $[a,c]$ is **strictly less than** $M$.
- But recall that at the beginning, we **defined** $M$ as the least upper bound of $f$ on the entire interval $[a,b]$. Using the same notation, this means $M$ is the least upper bound of $V_b$.
- So, if $b = c$, then $V_b = V_c$, so the least upper bound of $V_b < M$ but also the least upper bound of $V_b = M$ by definition of $M$, so $M < M$.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks @Hausdork

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$M = $ l.u.b. $f(t)$ as $t$ varies in $[a,b]$,

as defined in the first line of the proof.

$c$ is defined as the least upper bound of $X$.

If we determine that $c=b$, this means that, by the definition of $X$ and $V_x$, we have that

l.u.b.$X$ = l.u.b. $V_b$ = l.u.b. $f(t)$ as t varies in $[a,b]$. This is precisely what $M$ is. Stemming from the assumption that $f(c) < M$, this gives the contradiction.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have another question based from your answer. Is l.u.b. X comparable to l.u.b. V sub b?  Since X are some elements of the domain while V sub b are some elements of the range? Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: An upvote for your answer @Matt S. I understand now.